# Slicer filtered column with missing value in YTD

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have:

[image: table]

[image: Sex Dim]

[image: Relation]

YTD values with a date slicer shows:

[image]

But I like to see the Female value 30 on the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a date table in your model, you'll need a measure similar to this:

```
Value YTD = 
  var sDate = CALCULATE( LASTDATE(Sheet1[Date]), REMOVEFILTERS('Sex') )
  var result = TOTALYTD( SUM('Sheet1'[Value]), ALL('Sheet1'[Date]), 'Sheet1'[Date] <= sDate)
  RETURN COALESCE(result, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. Like to connect you in linkedin. alampmail@gmail.com